# Correct way to update live django web application

Tags: python, django, git, nginx

Before the actual problem let me explain our architecture. We are using git through ssh on our servers and have `post-recieve` hooks enabled to setup code. The code is all maintained in a separate folder. What we need is whenever a person pushes code to the server, it runs tests,migrations and updates it on live site. Currently whenever the application undergoes update in model it crashes.

What we need is a way that the hooks script detect if the code is proper, By proper i mean no syntax error etc, then run migrations and update the current application with the new codes without downtime. We are using nginx to proxy to django application,virtualenv for packages install from requirements.txt file and gunicorn for deployment.

The base line is that if there is failure at any point the push commit should be rejected. and if all tests are successfull, it should make migrations to dbs and start with the new app.

A though that i had was to use two ports for the same . One runing the main application and another with the push commits. If pushed codes were successfully tested , change port on nginx to git application and have nginx reload. Please discuss drawbacks of this application if any. And a sample post-commit script to show how to reject git commit in case of failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/). Fabric will allow you to create pythonic scripts and you can run deployments in remote server creating a new database and check whether the migrations are done safe. Once all good you can mention in your fabric script to deploy in prod or if fails mention in fabric to send an email.

This makes you life simple.